# Qual a diferença entre VisuAlg e Portugol?

Tags: característica-linguagem, portugol, visualg

Estou vendo aqui um grande *remexer* nas tags [visualg](/questions/tagged/visualg) e [portugol](/questions/tagged/portugol). Pelas wiki de tags, parece que VisuAlg seria o interpretador e Portugol seria a linguagem propriamente dita.

- VisuAlg é considerado como uma linguagem de programação?<sup>1</sup>
- Se sim, tem diferença sintática entre elas?
- Qual a distinção entre essas duas entidades?
- Portugol fora definido formalmente na década de 1980 pelos Professores Mannso e Nicolodi. O Portugol ensinado nas faculdades continua sendo compatível com o dessa definição? Ou houve alguma forma de agregar mais funcionalidades? Ou cada professor segue sua própria linguagem?
- Qual a grafia correta? visualg, VisuAlg, VisualG, Visualg, VISUALG?

### Leituras adicionais

<sub>(Que mesmo assim não fiquei totalmente satisfeito e continuei na dúvida)</sub>

- Artigo na [Wikipédia sobre VisuAlg](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg?wprov=sfti1)
- Artigo na [Wikipédia sobre Portugol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugol?wprov=sfti1)

### Notas

1. Estou usando uma definição mais branda de linguagem de programação que inclua pseudocódigos

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Primeiro vamos as definições de ambos.

**Definição de Portugol**:

> O Portugol é uma *pseudo-linguagem* algorítmica muito utilizada na
>   descrição de algoritmos, a qual destaca-se pelo uso de comandos em português,
>   o que facilita o aprendizado da lógica de programação, habituando o
>   iniciante com o formalismo de programação.

**Definição de VisuAlg (Visualizador de Algoritmos)** :

> VisuAlg é um aplicativo para Windows que permite editar, interpretar e
>   executar algoritmos com uma linguagem próxima do português estruturado
>   como um programa normal de computador.

Uma segunda definição de  VisuAlg:

> VisuAlg é uma ferramenta muito poderosa porém simples, parecida com o
>   Portugol, de grande popularidade nos meios acadêmicos e presente nos
>   livros mais utilizados.

Agora as perguntas:

> **VisuAlg é considerado como uma linguagem de programação?**

O VisuAlg é um interpretador criado pela Apoio Informática, ele lê e interpreta em uma linguagem **próxima do português estruturado**(Portugol) como um programa normal de computador.

A Atual Patente do VisuAlg está em nome de um dos desenvolvedores idealizadores do interpretador, Professor Antonio Carlos Nicolodi

> **Tem diferença sintática entre elas?**

Como no Update diz, até a Versão 2.0 a Linguagem oficial do VisuAlg era Portugol, entretanto a partir disso, visto que causava muitos inconvenientes por acentos, palavras com ou sem "ç"  .Em suma é uma versão do Portugol que não é `Case Sensitive`, e principalmente em seus comandos é aceito de mais de uma forma por exemplo o for que para o Portugol é apenas esta estrutura básica:
  `x de 1 ate 10 faca` 
 na linguagem do Visualg pode ser `FAÇA ATÉ` por exemplo(maiúsculo, sem o cedilha e com acento).
Estruturalmente falando não há quase nada , já que também é um pseudo código a forma de se estruturar os dados é a mesma

> **Qual a distinção entre essas duas entidades?**

Acredito que a definição e as respostas anteriores explicam essa questão.

> **Portugol fora definido formalmente na década de 1980 pelos Professores  Mannso e Nicolodi. O Portugol ensinado nas faculdades
>   continua sendo  compatível com o dessa definição? Ou houve alguma
>   forma de agregar  mais funcionalidades? Ou cada professor segue sua
>   própria linguagem?**

Não existe uma data definida para a Criação do Portugol, o que foi possível encontrar foi que a partir de 72 , com a instauração do Decreto [n° 70.370](http://www2.camara.leg.br/legin/fed/decret/1970-1979/decreto-70370-5-abril-1972-418827-publicacaooriginal-1-pe.html), com a criação da CAPRE(Comissão de Coordenação das Atividades de Processamento Eletrônico), que investimentos,  melhorias e padronizações relacionadas a área técnica do ramo, levando a crer que em meados da década de 70 foi também criado o Portugol já que entre as definições da CAPRE está:

> coordenar programas de treinamento em todos os níveis das técnicas
>   computacionais, fazendo uso dos recursos já existentes nas
>   universidades, escolas e centros de pesquisa

A partir de 2005(ano do lancamento do VisuAlg) comecou a ser utilizada em inúmeras universidades e locais de ensino, entretanto como o próprio professor esclareceu,ainda é o padrão ensinado para os locais de ensino, o mesmo não é mais válido para o VisuAlg, escolher ensinar com o VisuAlg , atualmente quer dizer aprender um dialeto do  Portugol, mas não ele, pelo menos não 100%, sua forma de desenvolvimento é a mesma( afinal é um pseudocódigo também), mas com algumas melhorias que o difere do Portugol, mas caso utilize o VisuAlg para ensino será a Linguagem padrão do compilador(Portugol modificado).

**Nota:** Carece de fontes mais técnicas para um resultado completo, entretanto, como dito em outra resposta, o @JoséDiz  teve contato ainda na década de 70, possivelmente surgindo entre o período datado (72) e o qual ele encontrou em seus livros(77).

> **Qual a grafia correta? visualg, VisuAlg, VisualG, Visualg, VISUALG?**

No site dos criadores está VisuAlg, com o "V" e o "A" maiúsculo portanto acredito que esta seja a grafia correta.
**Nota**: Atualmente se entrar na pagina oficial do VisuAlg 3.0(atual) está escrito VisualG, no manual esta VISUALG e visualg, porém até a versão 2.0 estava VisuAlg.

**Opinião pessoal:**
a Mudança acredito que foi mais uma forma de marketing , o logo novo do VisuAlg , está com o G e não o A em maiúsculo enquanto nas versões anteriores está na grafia antiga. No manual aparece diferente tanto do site quanto das versões anteriores,  acredito que não houve um cuidado para se escrever na grafia correta justamente por ser montado para ser algo didático, preferindo o conteúdo do que cuidar da maneira que se escreve VisuAlg, hoje não vejo muito problema de se escrever da forma que quiser, justamente por isso.

**UPDATE**

Entrei em contato com  o Professor Antonio Carlos Nicolodi, um dos criadores do Portugol e do VisuAlg e foi isso que ele disse:

> Quando fiz o Visualg (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg) junto com
>   o professor Cláudio nas primeiras versões até a 2.0 era só compatível
>   com o portugol puro porque no PORTUGOL usa-se comumente acentuações e
>   Ç (c cedilha) nas expressões (comandos e funções) e no Visualg não,
>   além disso no PORTUGOL só há comandos simples para a resolução dos
>   problemas, sem se preocupar com alguns recursos como LIMPARTELA que
>   limpa a tela do usuário, por exemplo.   Depois da versão 2.5 eu e o
>   Cláudio criamos novos comandos e recursos, que o portugol não possuía
>   ou não tinha.
>
> Na pseudo linguagem do Visualg (até a versão 2.5), tanto o professor
>   Claúdio, quanto eu,  criamos uma linguagem parecida com o portugol
>   pois era em minúsculo e não aceitavam "Ç, ç" e acentos como:  " é, ã "
>   da nossa língua portuguesa.
>
> Onde no PORTUGOL apareciam nos comandos de muitas literaturas (livros
>   e revistas) como:
>
> Ex.
>
> Para x de 1 até 10 Faça ....
>
> Já no VISUALG 2.0 ou 2.5 ficariam assim:
>
> para x de 1 ate 10 faca          //  (ate e não até ou faca e não
>   faça)   E como isso causava muitos transtornos para muitos usuários
>   (alunos/professores) podendo até não funcionar no Visualg, deixando o
>   usuário confuso, pois ele não sabia se tinha digitado corretamente ou
>   não mesmo tendo copiando corretamente do materiais disponíveis, eu
>   sempre os alertavam dizendo que a Linguagem do Visualg era uma versão
>   funcional mas não igual ao PORTUGOL (por isso deve-sem tomar cuidado)
>
> A partir da hora que o prof. Claúdio me deixou sozinho desenvolvendo
>   esse projeto  e eu criei a versão 3.0, (http://visualg3.com.br/)
>
> nesta versão eu decidi que isso iria mudar, assim por compatibilidade,
>   quando os algoritmos fossem escritos em minúsculos poderiam serem da
>   forma antiga
>
> ex. para x de 1 ate 10 faca
>
> Mas, quando os comandos fossem escritos em MAIÚSCULO poderão escrever
>   com acentuação e Ç (c cedilha) assim:
>
> ex. PARA x DE 1 ATÉ 10 FAÇA

**Referências**

- [O que é portugol?](http://www.c5.cl/ieinvestiga/actas/ribie98/118.html)
- [Definição de VisuAlg](http://www.techtudo.com.br/tudo-sobre/visualg.html)
- [Aprendendo algoritmo com VisuAlg](http://www.lcm.com.br/site/livros/detalhesLivro/f/aprendendo-algoritmo-com-visualg.html)
- [VisuAlg - Apoio Informática](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/visualg)
- [Definição - O que é VisuAlg?](http://img.submarino.com.br/manuais/113072140.pdf)

Comment: Nossa, muita *gentileza* sua compartilhar seu conhecimento :)

Comment: Daniel Gentil, veja se você tem como nos esclarecer isto: se em 1977 a UFMG já utilizava portugol para ensinar algoritmos estruturados nos cursos da área de ciências exatas (na disciplina Programação de Computadores), como é que "_Portugol fora definido formalmente na década de 1980 pelos Professores Mannso e Nicolodi_"?!  Tem algo de errado nessa afirmação de que o portugol foi criado por esses 2 professores...    ;)

Comment: @JoséDiz tive pouco contato, mas sim conheço, entretanto vale se definir que o Portugol do  VisuAlg e o padrão não são o mesmo, é como o sql... irei mudar alguns pontos da resposta, entretanto como o proprio em email disse "Linguagem do Visualg era uma versão funcional mas não igual ao PORTUGOL" ou seja Portugol != Portugol, porém com o mesmo nome

Comment: @JoséDiz Também adicionarei algumas considerações obrigado pela ajuda e por essa visão!

Comment: Nesta [imagem](http://videos.web-03.net/artigos/Thiago_Varallo/Introducao_VisuAlg/Introducao_VisuAlg1.jpg) de instalação, mostra claramente que a grafia seria "VisuAlg". Talvez um acrônimo de "**Visu**al **Alg**orítimo"

Comment: Acrônimo de Visualizador de Algoritmos* ainda sim, na ultima versão estavel (3.0) está  VisualG (com V e o G), mas ainda sim, no caso seria pela marca, já que nas anteriores não era

Answer (score 12):

Tomei contato com *portugol* em **1977**, como suporte no aprendizado de algoritmos estruturados. Por isto, estranhei a afirmação de que “*Portugol fora definido formalmente na década de 1980*”. Ora, como algo pode ter sido criado na década de 1980 se anos antes já era ensinado para centenas de alunos na disciplina Programação de Computadores, na UFMG?

Percebi também que há outras páginas na web que trazem a mesma [desinformação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desinforma%C3%A7%C3%A3o), tentando associar a criação do portugol a pessoas em específico... Como dito por Joseph Goebbels, “Uma mentira repetida mil vezes torna-se verdade”.

Portugol é somente uma pseudo linguagem para formalização de algoritmos estruturados, em que é utilizada a técnica de refinamentos sucessivos. Essa técnica envolve partir de um ponto abstrato e ir paulatinamente reduzindo o nível de abstração, até chegar ao ponto em que é possível codificar o algoritmo em alguma linguagem de computador. Na época, nos cursos de ciências exatas da UFMG era utilizada a linguagem [Algol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL), compilada, disponível em computador de grande porte (*[mainframe](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe)*) da [Burroughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_large_systems). Posteriormente, com o advento dos microcomputadores e o lançamento do [TurboPascal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal) pela empresa [Borland](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland), Pascal passou a ser a linguagem preferida por algumas instituições de ensino para o ensino de programação de computadores. Isto na década de 1980.

A origem do portugol está relacionada às ideias e livros de [Niklaus Wirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth), à época. Não por acaso ele tem relação com as linguagens Algol e Pascal.

Em minha opinião, qualquer tentativa de implementar interpretadores e compiladores de "portugol" cerceia toda a liberdade de criação disponível no portugol. Deixa de ser o portugol e passa a ser tão-somente uma caricatura do mesmo.

---

Eis trecho de texto encontrado na contracapa do livro [Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados](http://www.grupogen.com.br/algoritmos-e-estruturas-de-dados-18483):
*Foi introduzida uma pseudolinguagem (PORTUGOL) que permite ao leitor desenvolver algoritmos em Português de forma simples e intuitiva, independentemente de linguagem de programação (carregadas de restrições e exigências).

A implementação de algoritmos desenvolvidos em PORTUGOL é feita com facilidade a partir de um mapeamento para a linguagem de programação desejada.*

Comment: sua indagação reforça a tese que a linguagem do VisuAlg é mais um dialeto derivado, assim como se faz com java, openjdk... a partir do momento que voce simplifica a linguagem(comandos, funções) para uma forma que todos entendam não considera mais que seja a mesma linguagem, irei acrescentar em minha resposta algumas diferenças de desenvolvimento acredito que isso ajudará. no mais tenho um ponto de vista parecido, tive contato com o Visualg, nao o portugol e o contato que tive com o portugol achei muito similar ao pascal e nao a estrutura que eu vi no compilador

Comment: Achei uma referência que aponta para o que você disse: http://dicionario.sensagent.com/portugol/pt-pt/. Inclusive nela distingue **Portugol** e **PORTUGOL**

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pois é, quanto mais leio verbetes sobre portugol, mais encontro incorreções. Afora que criaram produtos com nomes como Portugol IDE, Portugol Online, G-Portugol, Portugol Studio etc etc, que mais confundem do que auxiliam...

Answer (score 8):

A linguagem que o VisuAlg interpreta é bem simples: é uma versão portuguesa dos pseudocódigos largamente utilizados nos livros de introdução à programação, conhecida como "Portugol". A linguagem do VisuAlg permite apenas um comando por linha: desse modo, não há necessidade de tokens separadores de estruturas, como o ponto e vírgula em Pascal. Também não existe o conceito de blocos de comandos (que correspondem ao begin e end do Pascal e ao { e } do C), nem comandos de desvio incondicional como o goto.

Na versão atual do VisuAlg, com exceção das rotinas de entrada e saída, não há nenhum subprograma embutido, tal como Inc(), Sqr(), Ord(), Chr(), Pos(), Copy() ou outro. O formato básico do nosso pseudocódigo é o seguinte:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 
// Seção de Declarações 
inicio
// Seção de Comandos 
fimalgoritmo
```

A primeira linha é composta pela palavra-chave algoritmo seguida do seu nome delimitado por aspas duplas. Este nome será usado como título nas janelas de leitura de dados (nas futuras versões do VisuAlg, talvez utilizemos este dado de outras formas).

A seção que se segue é a de declaração de variáveis, que termina com a linha que contém a palavra-chave inicio. Deste ponto em diante está a seção de comandos, que continua até a linha em que se encontre a palavra-chave fimalgoritmo.

> Fonte: http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem.htm

Answer (score 6):

Portugol é uma pseudo-linguagem, criado para demonstrar o uso de algoritmos. Está presente na maioria dos materiais didáticos, em português.

> Fonte: [http://www.wsantos.eti.br/computacao/conteudo.html?{C5396B5A-C41E-487E-B2C0-86F605CC01E0}.htm](http://www.wsantos.eti.br/computacao/conteudo.html?%7BC5396B5A-C41E-487E-B2C0-86F605CC01E0%7D.htm)

A linguagem que o VisuAlg interpreta é bem simples: é uma versão portuguesa dos pseudocódigos largamente utilizados nos livros de introdução à programação, conhecida como "Portugol".

> Fonte: http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem.htm

Answer (score 1):

O `VisuAlg`  é um programa que edita e executa algoritmos com uma linguagem próxima do português estruturado como se fosse um programa normal de computador.

O `Portugol` é uma pseudolinguagem que é utilizada desde meados dos anos 70 em apostilas, livros didáticos em ensino técnico de eletrônica. Hoje em dia também bastante utilizado para iniciar os estudos em programação para o individuo que está começando graduação em informática. (Para treinar o básico, lógica e estrutura de algoritmos)

 Agora você pode estar se perguntando:

Ta mas e qual é a diferença entre o VisuAlg e a pseudolinguagem Portugol?

Vamos lá... Inicialmente do projeto do programa Visualg tomaram como base a pseudolinguagem Portugol pois um dos envolvidos era o criador da linguagem. Após o criador do Portugol abandonar o projeto do VisuAlg... O outro desenvolvedor continuou o projeto para otimizar e melhorar o ambiente e a própria linguagem.

Essas otimizações e melhorias que ocorreram durante longo período, trouxe algumas novidade como o `SENÃO` que até então era senao, o FAÇA que até então era FACA, o ATÉ que até então era ate, não que até então era nao,...

A grafia correta é `VisuAlg`.

 A respeito da pergunta:

Portugol fora definido formalmente na década de 1980 pelos Professores Mannso e Nicolodi. O Portugol ensinado nas faculdades continua sendo compatível com o dessa definição? Ou houve alguma forma de agregar mais funcionalidades? Ou cada professor segue sua própria linguagem?

Levando em consideração que as duas tem o mesmo principio, a mesma base, a mesma lógica e a sintaxe semelhante (como expliquei a cima o VisuAlg teve melhoria na sintaxe), muitos professores assimilam as duas linguagens por serem parecidas ou até ensinam as duas deixando o aluno optar por uma na qual irá direcionar os estudos na matéria.

 Para ter uma melhor explicação http://visualg3.com.br/portugol-portugues-estruturado-e-visualg-como-tudo-comecou/.